# My DataTemplate is not displaying data in WPF app from an ObservableCollection<Task<myresultclass>>

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, task, observablecollection

I have created a WPF app that has an ObservableCollection>. This is bound to a ListBox which has a DataTemplate to display the information in a tidy manner.

When I run the app the ListBox populates the rows as expected... but no information is displayed in the DataTemplate.

Here are the Code Parts

**WINDOW XAML CODE**

```
<Window
    x:Class="web.app.smash.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:web.app.smash"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:web.app.smash.lib.Helpers;assembly=web.app.smash.lib"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    x:Name="MainPage"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.Resources>


        <DataTemplate x:Key="ResultListItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type m:ProcessedURLResult}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="12" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="12" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock
                        FontSize="8"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Text="Start time:" />
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="StartTime"
                        Width="50"
                        Margin="4,0,0,0"
                        FontSize="8"
                        Text="{Binding StartTime, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock
                        FontSize="8"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Text="End time:" />
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="EndTime"
                        Margin="4,0,0,0"
                        FontSize="8"
                        Text="{Binding EndTime, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock
                        FontSize="8"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Text="Milli seconds:" />
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="MilliSecondsTaken"
                        Margin="4,0,0,0"
                        FontSize="8"
                        Text="{Binding MillisecondsTaken, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock
                        FontSize="8"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Text="HTTP ststus code:" />
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="HTTPStatusCode"
                        Margin="4,0,0,0"
                        FontSize="8"
                        Text="{Binding HTTPStatusCode, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock
                        FontSize="8"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Text="Error message:" />
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="ErrorMessage"
                        Height="22"
                        Margin="4,0,0,0"
                        FontSize="8"
                        Text="{Binding ErrorMessage, Mode=OneWay}"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </StackPanel>

                <StackPanel
                    Grid.Row="3"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock
                        FontSize="8"
                        FontWeight="Bold"
                        Text="API results" />
                    <TextBlock
                        x:Name="APIResults"
                        Height="42"
                        Margin="4,0,0,0"
                        FontSize="8"
                        Text="{Binding APIResults, Mode=OneWay}"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                </StackPanel>




            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="32" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="0"
            Orientation="Vertical">
            <Button
                x:Name="SubmitCustomerGet"
                Margin="0,0,0,12"
                Click="SubmitCustomerGet_Click"
                Content="Get a Customer" />
            <Button
                x:Name="StartPerformanceTests"
                Margin="0,0,0,4"
                Click="StartPerformanceTests_Click"
                Content="Start Tests" />
            <Button
                x:Name="StopPerformanceTests"
                Margin="0,0,0,4"
                Click="StopPerformanceTests_Click"
                Content="Stop Tests" />
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel
            Grid.Row="0"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock x:Name="CountURLAdded" Background="#FFFBFFA7" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="CountURLWaiting" Background="#FFEA9393" />
            <TextBlock x:Name="CountURLFinished" Background="#FFB7EEB1" />
        </StackPanel>

        <TextBlock
            x:Name="InformationMessage"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
            Background="#FF646464" />

        <ListBox
            x:Name="ResultList"
            Grid.Row="2"
            Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
            ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource ResultListItemTemplate}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainPage, Path=AwesomeSauce, Mode=OneWay}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**WINDOW CODE BEHIND**

```
using System;
using System.Timers;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using web.app.smash.lib;
using web.app.smash.lib.Helpers;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading;
using Timer = System.Timers.Timer;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace web.app.smash
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //This is the URL to the webAPI
        private const string BASEURL = "http://localhost:23653/";


        public ObservableCollection<Task<ProcessedURLResult>> AwesomeSauce
        {
            get
            { return ocDownloadedTasks; }
            set
            { ocDownloadedTasks = value; }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<Task<ProcessedURLResult>> ocDownloadedTasks;

        private WebRequestCustomer wc = new WebRequestCustomer();
        private CancellationTokenSource cts;
        private CancellationToken ct;

        private HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        private long counturladded = 0;
        private long counturlwaiting = 0;
        private long counturlfinihed = 0;

        private Timer smashtimer;


        public MainWindow()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("App started");

            InitializeComponent();


            SetupTimer(1000);

            ocDownloadedTasks = new ObservableCollection<Task<ProcessedURLResult>>();

            ocDownloadedTasks.CollectionChanged += OcDownloadedTasks_CollectionChanged;

            ResultList.ItemsSource = ocDownloadedTasks;
        }

        private void OcDownloadedTasks_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach(Task t in e.NewItems)
            {
                if(t.Status == TaskStatus.Created)
                {
                    t.RunSynchronously();
                }
            }
        }

        private void SetupTimer(double interval)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Timer set to:" + interval.ToString());

            smashtimer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval);

            Debug.WriteLine("Timer event handler set");
            smashtimer.Elapsed += Smashtimer_Elapsed;

            smashtimer.AutoReset = true;
        }

        private void Smashtimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            //Debug.WriteLine("Timer event handler elapsed start: " + e.SignalTime.ToString());
            //this.urlList.Add(BASEURL);


            //Debug.WriteLine("ProcessAll: Returns a collection of tasks (In Loop)");
            //// ***Create a query that, when executed, returns a collection of tasks.
            //TasksList = from url in this.urlList select wc.ProcessPostURL(url, client, ct);

            //Debug.WriteLine("ProcessAll: Start processing the list of Tasks (In Loop)");
            //downloadTasks.AddRange(TasksList.ToList());


            //downloadTasks.Add(wc.ProcessPostURL(BASEURL, client, ct));

            App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
            {
                ocDownloadedTasks.Add(wc.ProcessPostURL(BASEURL, client, ct));
            });



            //TasksList = null;

            counturladded += 1;
        }

        private async void SubmitCustomerGet_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await wc.GetCustomerByID(BASEURL, 6);
            //ResponsesList.Inlines.Add(wc.DisplayResults);
            //ResponsesList.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
            InformationMessage.Text = "Get single customer";
        }

        private void StartPerformanceTests_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Start Performance button: Clicked");


            Debug.WriteLine("Start Performance button: Create the cancelation token");
            //Create the cancellation token
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            ct = cts.Token;

            Debug.WriteLine("Start Performance button: Timer started");
            smashtimer.Start();


            InformationMessage.Text = "Timer Started";
        }

        private void StopPerformanceTests_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Stop performance button: Clicked");

            Debug.WriteLine("Stop performance button: Timer stopped");
            smashtimer.Stop();
            InformationMessage.Text = "Timer Stopped";
        }

        //private void DisplayResults(ProcessedURLResult pur)
        //{
        //    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        //    if (pur.ErrorMessage==null)
        //    {
        //        sb.Append("Milliseconds: " + pur.MillisecondsTaken.ToString());
        //        sb.Append("API Result: " + pur.APIResults);


        //        ResponsesList.Inlines.Add(sb.ToString());
        //        ResponsesList.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());

        //    }
        //    else
        //    {
        //        sb.Append("Error: " + pur.ErrorMessage);

        //        ResponsesList.Inlines.Add(sb.ToString());
        //        ResponsesList.Inlines.Add(new LineBreak());
        //    }
        //    ResponsesList.InvalidateVisual();

        //}


        //private void DisplayInformation()
        //{
        //    CountURLAdded.Text = counturladded.ToString();
        //    CountURLWaiting.Text = counturlwaiting.ToString();
        //    CountURLFinished.Text = counturlfinihed.ToString();
        //}
    }
}
```

**PROCESSURLRESULTS CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace web.app.smash.lib.Helpers
{
    public class ProcessedURLResult : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _apiresults;
        private long _millisecondsTaken;
        private DateTime _startTime;
        private DateTime _endTime;
        private string _hTTPStatusCode;
        private string _errorMessage;

        public string APIResults
        {
            get
            {
                return _apiresults;
            }
            set
            {
                _apiresults = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(APIResults));
            }
        }

        public long MillisecondsTaken
        {
            get
            {
                return _millisecondsTaken;
            }
            set
            {
                _millisecondsTaken = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(MillisecondsTaken));
            }
        }

        public DateTime StartTime
        {
            get
            {
                return _startTime;
            }
            set
            {
                _startTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(StartTime));
            }
        }

        public DateTime EndTime
        {
            get
            {
                return _endTime;
            }
            set
            {
                _endTime = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(EndTime));
            }
        }

        public string HTTPStatusCode
        {
            get
            {
                return _hTTPStatusCode;
            }
            set
            {
                _hTTPStatusCode = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(HTTPStatusCode));
            }
        }

        public string ErrorMessage 
        {
            get
            {
                return _errorMessage;
            }
            set
            {
                _errorMessage = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ErrorMessage));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // Create the OnPropertyChanged method to raise the event
        private protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Talking Points**

The ObservableCollection holds Tasks of type ProcessURLResults, and to access these properties of ProcessURLResults you need to use the Results property of the task.

```
ocDownloadedTasks[0].Result.APIResults;
```

So how do I make the ListBox's DataTemplate get the Result property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tasks should be awaited.

Do not use `Task<ProcessedURLResult>` as item type. Instead, declare a (read-only) collection property like

```
public ObservableCollection<ProcessedURLResult> AwesomeSauce { get; } =
    new ObservableCollection<ProcessedURLResult>();
```

and populate it in an `async` method by awaiting the Task returned from the ProcessPostURL method:

```
private async void Smashtimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    var result = await wc.ProcessPostURL(BASEURL, client, ct)

    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => AwesomeSauce.Add(result));
}
```

---

There is also no need to assign the ListBox's ItemsSource in code behind if you bind it in XAML:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainPage, Path=AwesomeSauce}" .../>
```

---

You may also want to replace `System.Timers.Timer` by `DispatcherTimer` to avoid the need for calling `Dispatcher.Invoke`.

Comment: I like the DispatcherTimer suggestion and will make that change. Much appreciated thanks 

Comment: Also make the other changes :-)

Comment:  i have just made all the changes and it work fantastically. However I was not able to use the `DispatcherTimer` because the Interval property only timed in seconds and did not get the smaller ticks i needed. But it is good to know that that timer exists thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think that your template binding type mismatch.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ResultListItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type m:ProcessedURLResult}">
```

is different from

```
public ObservableCollection<Task<ProcessedURLResult>> AwesomeSauce
```

and

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MainPage, Path=AwesomeSauce, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

is redundant. you have the assign code in MainWindow()

```
ResultList.ItemsSource = ocDownloadedTasks;
```

try to use wrapper class. for instance

```
public class ResultWrapper
{
    public Task<ProcessedURLResult> InnerTask { get; set; }

    public ProcessedURLResult Result
    {
        get
        {
            return InnerTask.Result;
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
public ObservableCollection<ResultWrapper> AwesomeSauce
```

XAML is

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ResultListItemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ResultWrapper}">
...
    <TextBlock
                    x:Name="StartTime"
                    Width="50"
                    Margin="4,0,0,0"
                    FontSize="8"
                    Text="{Binding Result.StartTime, Mode=OneWay}" />
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `DataType` to `Task` (or remove it completely) and then adjust the binding paths:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Task}">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Result.ErrorMessage}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

**Note**
You definitely should avoid `Task.RunSynchronously()` as there are scenarios where it will produce a deadlock. `Task` are designed for asynchronous or concurrent programming.
To have code execute synchronously and deferred at some random time you should make use of delegates and use one of the `Action` overloads (`Action<ProcessedURLResult>` in your scenario).

Then don't bind to this delegate collection directly (or `Task` collection) but to a dedicated result collection of type `ProcessedURLResult` you can bind the `ItemsSource` to. This will give you Intellisense support in XAML too, when writing the `DataTemplate`.

Whether you use `Action` or stick to `Task` you will experience UI freeze. Depending on the individual execution time and count of items, i.e. total execution time, this freeze will be more or less noticable but is always not desireable and should/ can be avoided. Therefore if you have access to `WebRequestCustomer` consider to make it run asynchronously (e.g., using `TaskCompletionSource` in case of posting HTTP requests).

Also your code is mixing both ways to populate the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`: you are using `Binding` and direct assignment. The latter will override the former and behaves differently. I recommend `Binding` set from XAML.